# Laravel DataTables multiple select with checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, checkbox, datatables

I am developing an application in Laravel with DataTables where i display data form Mysql database. How to do multiple selection with line color for each selection ? like this [link](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) but with multiple selection and how to get values from the selected line not just the line id and how to get the current line values when click on the corresponding button of that line ?

Each button of the last column open a form with a submit button, the submit function is for all the blue buttons.

This is a screenshot of the app:

[image]

Here is code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#pdr_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "{{ route('ajaxdata.getdata') }}",
    "columns":[
        { "data": "checkbox", orderable:false, searchable:false},
        { "data": "ID_Piece" },
        { "data": "Designation" },
        { "data": "Status" },
        { "data": "action"}
    ],
    //"order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){ 
        if(data.Status == 'Disponible'){ 
            $(row).find('td:eq(3)').css('background-color', 'green').css('color', 'white'); 
        }
        if(data.Status == 'Indisponible'){ 
            $(row).find('td:eq(3)').css('background-color', 'red').css('color', 'white'); 
        } 
    }
 });    

$(document).on('click', '.Ajouter_au_panier', function(){
    $('#pdrModal').modal('show');
    $('#pdr_form')[0].reset();
    $('#form_output').html('');
    $('#piece').text('PDR'); 
});

$(document).on('click', '.pdr_checkbox', function(){//How to color the entire line and get all the values of that line

});

$('#pdr_form').on('submit', function(event){//How to get all the values for the line of that button
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('ajaxdata.postdata') }}",
        method:"get",
        data:form_data,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            if(data.error.length > 0)
            {
                var error_html = '';
                for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
                {
                    error_html += '<div class="alert alert-danger">'+data.error[count]+'</div>';
                }
                $('#form_output').html(error_html);
            }
            else
            {                            
                $('#form_output').html(data.success);
                $('#pdr_form')[0].reset();
                $('#pdr_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Controller:

```
function getdata()
    {
     $pdrs = Pdrs::select('ID_Piece', 'Designation', 'Status');
     return DataTables::of($pdrs)
            ->addColumn('checkbox', '<input type="checkbox" name="pdr_checkbox[]" class="pdr_checkbox" value="{{$ID_Piece}}" />')
            ->rawColumns(['checkbox','action'])
            ->addColumn('action', function($pdr){
                return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary Ajouter_au_panier" id="'.$pdr->ID_Piece.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Ajouter au panier</a>';})
            ->make(true);            
    }
```

Comment: And how you are deciding those colors, as there are different colors showing the image ?

Comment: I mean hover the line when click on checkbox just a color that differentiates the selected lines from the non-selected lines.

Comment: You did not implement any of the code from the link you provided. You need to add a `select` property to your config.

Comment: The link i provided is for comprehension only.

Comment: I updated my post, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select: {
   style:'multi',
},
```

if you don't intend to use `style:'multi'`
use **CTRL+Select** for multiple selection under `style:'os',`
as given in the documentation in the link provided by you.
[Check Here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/select.style)

Then, you can do a $.each on the selected checkboxes within the ajax click function and form the data variable that you want to submit to the controller.
Also, please follow the code of the documentation.

```
$('#someSubmitButton').on('submit', function(e){
  //Place submit button within the form
  var form = this;
  //Define your dataTable to a variable - here it is table
  var rows_selected = table.column(0).checkboxes.selected();

  // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
  $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){.... Your other code goes 
  here based on how you want to handle.....}
```

Comment: Can you provide the working code, `$('#pdr_table').DataTable({...`

Comment: I am adding the checkboxes manually from the controller, this code will not work for me.

Comment: It will still work, $.each doesn't mind, whether you load data from controller or, the datatable loads it for you. It is just a script you need to put in your submit function, and form your data variable and pass into ajax function. Incase you are generating the checkboxes manually, don't refer to the datatable link, it wont help you much. For marking the row , you have to invoke an onclick function..and change the css attribute for the background-colour for the row.

Comment: var items= [];
    $('.selected-items-class').each(function(i){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
      items.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

Comment: Try the above way to get all the data from the selected rows.

Comment: How and Where do i trigger the checkboxes ?

Comment: After **$('#pdr_form').on('submit', function(event){ and before $.ajax({**

Comment: And for the "how" i have already wrote a sample items variable

Comment: It just returning the line id, i want to get all the values from the selected line, also i want to get the current line values when click on the button of that line, for the hover the event must be outside the submit function, can you give a full answer for those questions, so i can approuve it ?

Comment: Make use of data-attributes to get respective values in an array. I guess I have given sufficient explanation to you. You might have to go through the basics of jQuery to proceed further.